# Bootstrap Glyphicon (collapse and expand) in not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement Bootstrap `glyphicon-plus` and `glyphicon-minus`. But when I click on `glyphicon-plus`, the content expands but `glyphicon-plus` does not change to `glyphicon-minus`.

This is the code:

```
<button type="submit" value="Button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button> 
<div class="container">
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <div>
           Hi there!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript` Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });
</script>
```

Where I am going wrong. Please guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).parent()` is the `<div class="container">` which does not contain an element with `class="glyphicon-plus"`

You need to find the `<button>` and then the `<span>` within the `<button>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev('button').find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev('button').find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });
</script>
```

As a side note, you could simplify this by using just `.toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus')` to add and remove the class names.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse, hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().prev('button').find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the code which you provided but still not working in my application.

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: still that + sign is not changing

Comment: And what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: or can you please create simple fiddle based on this scenario? It will be really helpful, Stephen.

Comment: I assume that is not all your html because the `<div id="demo" class="collapse">` element does not contain anything related to 'shown.bs.collapse' so now I'm not sure what your trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160981/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).closest('div.container').prev("button").find("span.glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).closest('div.container').prev("button").find("span.glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" value="Button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button> 
<div class="container">
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <div>
           Hi there!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used:

- `closest` to find the parent element **(container class)**
- `prev` to get the previous element **(button)**
- `find` to get the span within button

Hope this will help you.